# Number of days between two Time instances

Tags: ruby, date, time

**How can I determine the number of days between two Time instances in Ruby?**

```
> earlyTime = Time.at(123)
> laterTime = Time.now
> time_difference = laterTime - earlyTime
```

I'd like to determine the number of days in `time_difference` (I'm not worried about fractions of days. Rounding up or down is fine).

Comment: Do you care about daylight savings time?

Comment: good question. accounting for daylight savings time and leap years is not critical as this calculation just prompts an email reminder to a few people.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Difference of two times is in seconds. Divide it by number of seconds in 24 hours.

```
(t1 - t2).to_i / (24 * 60 * 60)
```

Comment: @Tallboy what I do is store everything in `UTC` and do these calculations with `Time` instances of `zone` `UTC`. Daylight savings time will appropriately show when rendering any `Time` in a view.

Comment: @GonZifroni   so add .utc in the code? (t1.utc - t2.utc) / (24*60*60)  or if using (some of) rails' gems:  (t1.utc-t2.utc)/1.days

Comment: If this is Rails you can use `(t1 - t2).to_i / 1.day.seconds`

Answer (score 19):

```
require 'date'
days_between = (Date.parse(laterTime.to_s) - Date.parse(earlyTime.to_s)).round
```

**Edit** ...or more simply...

```
require 'date'
(laterTime.to_date - earlyTime.to_date).round
```

Comment: Stringifying times just to parse them right away seems a little weird to me :)

Answer (score 12):

```
earlyTime = Time.at(123)
laterTime = Time.now
time_difference = laterTime - earlyTime
time_difference_in_days = time_difference / 1.day  # just divide by 1.day
```

Comment: I'm sorry, you mentioned Ruby but not specifically Ruby on Rails. I don't think you'll get the 1.day functionality in vanilla ruby.

Comment: that's correct, you don't. Unless you require proper part of active_support.

Answer (score 5):

```
[1] pry(main)> earlyTime = Time.at(123)
=> 1970-01-01 01:02:03 +0100
[2] pry(main)> laterTime = Time.now
=> 2014-04-15 11:13:40 +0200
[3] pry(main)> (laterTime.to_date - earlyTime.to_date).to_i
=> 16175
```

Answer (score 4):

To account for DST (Daylight Saving Time), you'd have to count it by the days. Note that this assumes less than a day is counted as 1 (rounded up):

```
num = 0
cur = start_time
while cur < end_time
  num += 1
  cur = cur.advance(:days => 1)
end
return num
```

Comment: too slow for general use

Answer (score 4):

### in_days (Rails 6.1+)

Rails 6.1 introduces new [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) conversion methods like [in_seconds](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_seconds), [in_minutes](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_minutes), [in_hours](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_hours), [in_days](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_days), [in_weeks](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_weeks), [in_months](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_months), and [in_years](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_years).

As a result, now, your problem can be solved as:

```rb
date_1 = Time.parse('2020-10-18 00:00:00 UTC')
date_2 = Time.parse('2020-08-13 03:35:38 UTC') 

(date_2 - date_1).seconds.in_days.to_i.abs
# => 65
```

Here is [a link to the corresponding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38699).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple answer that works across DST:

`numDays = ((laterTime - earlyTime)/(24.0*60*60)).round`

60*60 is the number of seconds in an hour
24.0 is the number of hours in a day.  It's a float because some days are a little more than 24 hours, some are less.  So when we divide by the number of seconds in a day we still have a float, and round will round to the *closest* integer.

So if we go across DST, either way, we'll still round to the closest day.  Even if you're in some weird timezone that changes more than an hour for DST.

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers will actually work if you don't want to estimate and you want to take into account daylight savings time.
For instance 10 AM on Wednesday before the fall change of clocks and 10 AM the Wednesday afterwards, the time between them would be 1 week and 1 hour.  During the spring it would be 1 week minus 1 hour.
In order to get the accurate time you can use the following code

```
def self.days_between_two_dates later_time, early_time
   days_between = (later_time.to_date-early_time.to_date).to_f
   later_time_time_of_day_in_seconds = later_time.hour*3600+later_time.min*60+later_time.sec
   earlier_time_time_of_day_in_seconds = early_time.hour*3600+early_time.min*60+early_time.sec
   days_between + (later_time_time_of_day_in_seconds - early_time_time_of_day_in_seconds)/1.0.day   
end
```